# When I using variable parameters, it works well with int and double, but when it comes to float, error happens

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, c++11

When I using variable parameters, it works well with int and double, but when it comes to float, error happens.

Here is the code.

```
void vaParamTest(int a, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, a);
    for (int  i = 0; i < a; i++)
        printf("%f\t", va_arg(ap, float));
    putchar('\n');
    va_end(ap);
}
```

I pass parameters like this.

```
vaParamTest(3, 3.5f, 8.3f, 5.1f);
```

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever. But what error message are you getting? What output? I mean, you are getting something, right?

Comment: You might want to explain a bot more about what "error happens"... Compilation error? Runtime error? Output not what expected? I suspect the last, as `3` (the first argument) is not a float.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variables that are passes as variadic function arguments are **default-promoted**, which makes all `float`s into `double`s. You can never have a `float` argument (just like [you can never have a `char` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11985774/596781)). In `printf`, `%f` always means `double`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but now I'm even more confused.

I find this paragraph [6.5.2.2] in your link.
Obviously, there is no question for the description of integer promotions.  When pass char s to a function, for example, void paramStack(char x, char y, char z), all char s is 4 Bytes.

However, for double promotions, void paramStack(float x, float y, float z), all floats take 4 Bytes, not 8 bytes like double. I can find like this,
&x: 0x0040fe10
&y: 0x0040fe14
&z: 0x0040fe18

Do double promotions happens in this function?

Comment: @Robert - No, this is all about the `...` part. Rules are different there, because the compiler doesn't know the intended types.

Comment: @Bo Persson- Thank you. The **double promotions** only happens when there is no parameter for a given argument, but for an ordinary function call, another rule works, Is that right?

Comment: @Robert - Yes, when the parameter type is known, the argument is promoted to that type (if needed). The `...` is special, so it has special rules.

Comment: @Robert: There are certain times when a value is default-promoted. Being a variadic argument (i.e. matching the ellipsis) is such a time. Default-promotion entails that float values are converted to and passed as doubles. An ordinary, prototyped function like `void f(char, float, short);` still works as expected! (The linked question focuses on integral default promotions, so the part about float-to-double may not be mentioned there, though it's nearby in the standards.)