# Wrong format specifiers in scanf (or) printf

Tags: c, input, printf, scanf

As of the `printf` function is concerned, I understand the following from few references and experiments.

- When we try to print an integer value with **format specifiers that are used for float (or) double** and vice the versa the behaviour is **unpredictable**.
- But it is possible to use `%c` to print the character equivalent of the integer value. Also using of `%d` to print ASCII value (integer representations) of character is acceptable.

Similarly, what is the behaviour of `scanf`, if there is a **mismatch of format specifier and the arguements passed to scanf**. Does the standards define it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variadic arguments (those matching the ellipsis, `...`) are *default-promoted*. That means that all shorter integral types are promoted to `int` (or unsigned, as appropriate). There's no difference between inte­gers and characters ([I believe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985774/is-char-default-promoted)). The difference between `%d` and `%c` in `printf` is merely how the value is *formatted*.

`scanf` is a different kettle of fish. All the arguments you pass are *pointers*. There's no default-pro­mo­tion among pointers, and it is crucial that you pass the exact format specifier that matches the type of the pointee.

In either case, if your format specifier doesn't match the supplied argument (e.g. passing an `int *` to a `%p` in `printf`), the result is *undefined behaviour*, which is far worse than being "unpredictable" -- it means your program is simply ill-formed.

Comment: I'm not sure that "ill-formed" is the best way to describe it. If the behavior is undefined, your program is basically incorrect, but the implementation isn't required to warn you about it.

Comment: “passing an `int*` to a `%p` in printf()” is perhaps not the most didactic example, since so many C programmers think that it is correct. It might be better to use a more obviously wrong example first (e.g. `int*` to `%f`) and then perhaps include the information that passing `int*` to `%p` is technically incorrect as well.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Hm, I thought it was didactic precisely *because* many people think -- erroneously -- that this is correct.

Comment: @KerrekSB It is your answer. This was only a suggestion. To put it differently, I think your answer is great for developers who already know that `void*` and `int*` are incompatible, and confusing for the others.

Comment: @KerrekSB, could you  supply a standard reference? I am particularly interested in passing `int` to `%c`. Is that an UB?

Comment: @Arkadiy: C11 7.21.6.1p9: "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

`printf` and `scanf` are confusing, because they're pretty special and unusual functions.  Both of them accept a *variable number of arguments*.  And this means that the rules for matching the types of the arguments, and the automatic conversions that might happen, are different than for other functions.

For most functions, the compiler knows exactly what type(s) of arguments(s) are expected.  For example, if you call

```
#include <math.h>

int i = 144;
printf("%f\n", sqrt(i));
```

it works fine.  The `sqrt` function expects an argument of type `double`, but the compiler knows this, so it can insert an automatic conversion, just as if you had written

```
printf("%f\n", sqrt((double)i));
```

(Footnote: The compiler knows about `sqrt`'s expected argument type from the function prototype found in `<math.h>`.)

But `printf` accepts a variable number of arguments, of any types.  You can pass just about anything, as long as the format specifiers match:

```
int i1 = 12, i2 = 34;
float f1 = 56.78, f2 = 9.10;
printf("%d %d %f %f\n", i1, i2, f1, f2);
printf("%f %f %d %d\n", f1, f2, i1, i2);
```

But that's the key: *as long as the format specifiers match*.  In a call to a function with a variable number of arguments, like `printf`, the compiler does not attempt (it's not even *allowed* to attempt) to convert each argument to the type expected by the corresponding format specifier.  So if there are gross mismatches, like trying to use `%f` to print an integer, it doesn't work, and in fact crazy things can happen.

But, just to keep things interesting, when you call a function that takes a variable number of arguments, like `printf`, there's another set of conversions that are automatically performed.  They're called the *default argument promotions*.  Basically, anything of type `char` or `short` is automatically converted ("promoted") to `int`, and anything of type `float` automatically converted to `double`.  So you can get away with *some* mismatches: you can print a `char` or a `short` using `%d`, and you can print either a `float` or a `double` using `%f`.  And since `char` is always promoted to `int`, that means `%c` is actually going to receive an `int`, and this means you can pass a regular `int` and print it with `%c`, also.

But it's easy to get this stuff wrong, especially since we're used to the compiler converting everything properly for us when we call other functions, like `sqrt`.  So, a good compiler will peek at the format string, and use it to predict what types of arguments you ought to pass, and if you're passing something wrong, the compiler can issue a warning.  If your compiler isn't issuing such warnings, it would be a good idea to figure out how to enable them, or if not, perhaps get a better compiler.

And then we come to `scanf`.  `scanf` also accepts a variable number of arguments, which are supposed to match the specifiers on the format string.  However, for `scanf`, *all* of the arguments you pass are pointers, to variables of yours which you're asking `scanf` to fill in with the values it reads.  And it turns out this means that *no* automatic conversions are possible, and you must pass all arguments as pointers of exactly the right type.  Here is a table listing some of them:

| specifier | corresponding argument |
| --- | --- |
| `%c` | pointer to `char` |
| `%hd` | pointer to `short` |
| `%d` | pointer to `int` |
| `%ld` | pointer to `long` |
| `%f` | pointer to `float` |
| `%lf` | pointer to `double` |
| `%s` | pointer to `char` [note] |

So there's no automatic conversion from `char` and `short` to `int` like there is for `printf`, and there's no automatic conversion from `float` to `double`  If you're reading a `float` you have to use `%f`, and if you're reading a `double` you have to use `%d`.

Again, though, a good compiler will warn you about any mismatches, and it's a very good idea to seek out and pay attention to those warnings!

There is one "conversion" that happens automatically when you call `scanf`, but it has nothing to do with `scanf`.  If you're using `%s` to read a string, you're supposed to pass an argument of type pointer-to-`char`, although it has to be a pointer to some number of contiguous characters, because `scanf` probably isn't going to read a single character; it's probably going to read a string of several characters.  So it's pretty common to pass `scanf` an *array* of characters, and this is okay, because whenever you use an array in an expression in C, like when you pass it to a function (like `scanf`), the value that gets used is a pointer to the array's first element, which works just fine, and is what `scanf` is expecting.  That is, both

```
char *p = malloc(10);
scanf("%9s", p);
```

and

```
char a[1-];
scanf("%9s", a);
```

will work.  (And note that this is the one case where you do *not* need to use a `&` on a variable you pass to `scanf`.)