# Why array prints sometimes values and sometimes addresses?

Tags: c, arrays

Could you explain why in the first program "array[ counter ]" prints values but in the second program "array[ counter ]" prints addresses?

FIRST PROGRAM

```
main()
{
    int array[ 4 ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int counter;
    for( counter = 0 ; counter <= 3; counter++ )
        printf( "%u\n", array[ counter ]);
}
```

SECOND PROGRAM

```
main()
{
    int array[ 4 ] [ 1 ]= { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int counter;
    for( counter = 0 ; counter <= 3; counter++ )
        printf( "%u\n", array[ counter ]);
}
```

Comment: Same if you do:
`int* i[4];`

`printf("%u", i);`

Comment: Because in the first program you have an array of integers and in the second program you have an array of arrays. Change the second program to use array[counter][0] and you'll get the same results for both.

Comment: Thanks to all of you!. I understood specially while reading your comment Jim Balter. Array[counter] always prints the values, in the first program the values are the numbers, in the second program the values are the addresses of the inner array wich has numbers.

Comment: BTW, if you compile this with gcc -Wall it will warn you that your initializer in the second program is missing curly braces ... it should be { {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} }. Also instead of `main()` use `int main(void)`, and if you're using a pre-C99 compiler you need to return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case the type of `array[counter]` is `int [1]` while in the first case the type of `array[counter]` is `int`.

`int [1]` is an array type and when you print it, it ***decays*** to a pointer referring to the start address of this array. That's what you get when you print it.

Comment: Yay, someone got it right! It's depressing how many people are claiming that `array` and `array[count]` are pointers.

Answer (score 2):

In the second example `array[counter]` isn't a value, it's an array.

When you pass an array as a parameter to a function, it undergoes the [array to pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/1007504), and therefore you get a pointer to the beginning of the array, rather than the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the second program, `array` is a pointer to a pointer to a list of `int`s. In the first program, `array` is a pointer to a list of `int`s.

Thus, when you dereference `array` in the second program you get a pointer to a list of `int`s – in other words, you get a memory address. Similarly, when you dereference `array` in the first program, you get the first element in the list of `int`s – in other words, a value.

Comment: No, `array` is not a pointer in either case ... please learn the basics of this issue, which gets discussed ad nauseam at SO. Just because an array is converted to a pointer to its first element in expression contexts doesn't mean an array is a pointer. And you have the two programs reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is quite ordinarily printing all four elements of the array in a loop, nothing special to see.

---

Your second example on the other hand is simply wrong.

This defines an array of 4 array of 1 `it`:

```
int array[4][1] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

This orders `print` to output the value of one `unsigned`, [though it gives a `int[1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12830052) which [automatically decays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432) to `int*`.
That is [Undefined Behavior (UB)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984), anything may happen (if `int`s and `int*` are the same size, it might even happen to print the pointer).

```
printf( "%u\n", array[ counter ]);
```

Comment: @JimBalter: It's allowed and well-defined as long as the `int` is non-negative.

Comment: Hmmm ... the standard says "The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal (u)" ... but under va_arg it says "the behavior is undefined, except for the following
cases: one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types ..." ... so I guess you're right. Still, it's bad practice, and "wrong" in that sense.

Comment: @JimBalter: There's more fun to be had with conversion to some signed integer type...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the following codes means the same thing, since the format string is "%u":
1. printf("%u\n", xxxx);
2. printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)xxxx);

Secondly:
1. The type of array[counter] is "int" in the first program.
2. The type of array[counter] is "int *" in the second program. 

Finally:
1. If you convert "int" to "unsigned int", you will get values.
2. If you convert "int *" to "unsigned int", you will certainlly get addresses.

I hope that solved your problem.

Comment: "First of all" -- wrong; if xxxx isn't an unsigned int, the version without a cast is undefined behavior. "Secondly" -- wrong; the type of array[counter] is int[4]. "Finally" -- wrong; you get undefined behavior. On a machine where ints are shorter than pointers, you will probably get the low-order bits of an address.

Comment: Correction: the type of array[counter] is int[1]

Comment: Another correction: `printf("%u\n", xxxx)` is defined *if* xxxx is an int that can be represented as an `unsigned int` ... so it would be undefined if `array` contained negative numbers. Again, it's wrong to say they the two statements mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. You made it much clear. But if ints are shorter than pointers, endianness might also play a role in the convertion of pointers to ints. I just don't know how to verify.

Comment: Printing a pointer with %u could produce either the high or low order bits, depending on endianness, but casting a pointer to a shorter int type doesn't depend on endianness, it just uses the low order bits (in practical, existing implementations; the C standard doesn't define the behavior). To verify, you would need access to machines with different endianness.

Answer (score 0):

`int array[4][1]` is equivalent to `int *array[4]`
So you will be getting the address stored in array.