# Use scanf in if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, output

Why the output is '4' ? , while input is 'A'

```
int main() {  int a = 5;  
if(scanf("%d",&a))  
printf("%d",a+1);  
else  
printf("%d",a-1);  
}
```

Comment: 'A' is a character, not an integer, %d scans for an integer

Answer (score 2):

When type sepcifier `%d` is used then the function expects that a valid signed decimal integer number will be entered. It is evident that symbol `'A'`  is not a number so the input failed.

Now a question arises: what will the function return in this case?

According to the description of function `scanf`  (the C Standard, 7.21.6.4 The scanf function):

> 3 The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
>   failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
>   Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items
>   assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, **or even zero, in the
>   event of an early matching failure**.

So the condition in the if statement

```
if(scanf("%d",&a))
```

evaluated to 0 (false) and the else statement was executed.

```
else  
printf("%d",a-1);
```

that outputed 4.

Take into account that in general you may enter symbol `'A'` for integers. But in this case the corresponding integer variable must be declared as `unsigned`and format specifier of `scanf` must to be `%x`

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int a = 5;

    if ( scanf( "%x", &a ) )
    {      
        printf( "%u\n", a + 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%u\n", a - 1 );
    }
}
```

In this case the output will be `11`.:) `scanf` will consider symbol `'A'` as a hexadecimal representation of 10.

Answer (score 1):

You instructed `scanf` to read a signed integer. The input didn't even start with a sign or digit, so `scanf` didn't find a signed integers, so `scanf` returned `0` (the number of input items successfully matched and assigned), dropping you into the `else` clause of the `if`. Since `scanf` didn't match anything, it didn't assign anything, meaning `a` wasn't changed, and `a-1` is `4`.

You didn't specify what you were expecting, so I don't know what fix to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In scanf() All the arguments you pass are pointers. There's no default-pro­mo­tion among pointers, and it is crucial that you pass the exact format specifier that matches the type of the pointer.

for more clearance:-
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830052/wrong-format-specifiers-in-scanf-or-printf)!