# How the printf function works in c when format specifier is not correct?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

In an Interview, I was asked the output of the following code snippet:

```
printf("%d", "computer");
```

I am a c# developer and earlier I had learned C too, but when this question was asked, I had no clue. 
When I run the same question in windows 10 computer (64-bit), it is giving putput as

> 3571712

Please give reasons why this is happening.

Comment: See also: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380628/how-printf-works-in-case-of-type-mismatch-with-type-specifier) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648596/why-are-arguments-which-do-not-match-the-conversion-specifier-in-printf-undefine).

Comment: Either it was intentionally a tricky question to see if you knew that the code doesn't make sense, or it was unintentionally a complete crap question, in which case you didn't want that job anyway. The correct answer is _not_ "it will print the address of the string literal", because it uses the wrong format specifier for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In an Interview, I was asked the output of the following code snippet [...]

Your answer could have been:

a. "This is undefined behavior"

b. "A number will most likely be printed, but I cannot tell you which number because I do not know where the string is stored, as the string's address will be attempted to be interpreted as an integer by the `printf` function".

c. "Which platform? Which compiler?"

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't *"work"*, what you observe is an outcome of **[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1/p9

> [...] If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

In your case, the conversion specifier is `%d` which expects an argument of type `int` but you're supplying a `char*`, and they are not the compatible type, hence the UB.

Answer (score 4):

well value of `"computer"` is memory address where that string is stored. It could be value of that address is: 3571712 (But you should not rely on this - see below).

But to print memory address `void*` you should use `%p` format specifier. And using incorrect format specifiers is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work it's giving the garbage value of these variables. And the main reason is that we use "%d" for the output of int not for string.