# C Program That asks If the User wants to Convert from C to F then does the conversion

Tags: c, if-statement, integer, temperature

I have an assignment to create a program that asks the user what temperature they want to convert and then convert it, but my if statements are not working.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
//Declare Variables
float ce; //Celcius
float fa; //Fahrenheit
char in; //Input form user
float go; //If a loop should keep running

//Ask the user what they would like to convert
printf("Would you like to convert from Celsius 'C' or Fahrenheit 'F'?\n");

//Get the input from the user
scanf("%d", &in);

//Start the Loop
go = 1;
while (go == 1) {
    if (in == 'F')  { //If the user wants to convert from Fahrenheit
        //Stop the loop
        go = 0;

        //Ask the user the temperature they would like to convert
        printf("What temperature F would you like to convert to C?\n");

        //Get the input from the user
        scanf("%d", &fa);

        //Crunch the Numbers
        ce = ((fa - 32)/1.8);

        //Print the answer
        printf("The temperature in Celcius is %lf\n", ce);

    } else if (in == 'C') { //If the user wants to convert from Celcius
        //Stop the loop
        go = 0;

        //Ask the user the temperature they would like to convert
        printf("What temperature C would you like to convert to F?\n");

        //Get the input from the user
        scanf("%d", &ce);

        //Crunch the Numbers
        fa = (32 + (ce * 1.8));

        //Print the answer
        printf("The temperature in Fahrenheit is %lf\n", fa);

    } else {
        //make sure the loop will continue running
        go = 1;

        //Print an error message
        printf("That is an invalid input, please enter either a 'C' of 'F'\n");

        //Take the input again
        scanf("%d", &in);
    }
}

//End the program
return 0;

}
```

No matter what i enter, It keeps coming back with "That is an invalid input..."

How can i get my if statements to work? I have also tried strcmp only to get a "Comparison between pointer and integer" Error. This should be a fairly simple and basic program and yet I can't get it to work.

Comment: It is somewhat unlikely that a decimal integer is `'F'` or `'C'`. On ascii, the numeric values of these characters are `70` and `67`, respectively.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &in);`, how? `in` is a `char`...

Comment: `scanf("%d", &in);` is looking for a number. `scanf("%c", &in);` scans for a letter. See: [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem** :

In your code `in` is declared as `char` but,you are using wrong format specifier in `scanf()` i.e, `%d` while scanning `in`..

`scanf("%d",&in)`

---

**Solution**:

to avoid scan using `%c` as format specifier in `scanf()`

`scanf(" %c",&in)`

> **Note**: I've given `space` infront of `%c` to consume white spaces that might come from newline characters (`\n`) entered at the end of previous `scanf()` statements

---

*In `scanf()` all the arguments you pass are pointers, and it is mandatory that you pass the exact format specifier that matches the type of the variable present at that address.*

To know more about what happens when wrong format specifier is used in `scanf()` or `printf()` see this : [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830052/wrong-format-specifiers-in-scanf-or-printf)

Answer (score 1):

Use Switch() Statement its better in this case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
float c,f,k;
int choice;
printf("Which Scale do you want to convert\n 1.Celsius\n 2.Fahrenheit\n 3.Kelvin");
printf("\n Enter Your Choice: ");
scanf("%d",&choice);
switch(choice)
{
    case 1:  printf("Enter Celsius Temperature: ");
             scanf("%f",&c);
             f=(9*c+32)/5;
             k=c+273;
             printf("\nThe Temperature is %.2f in Fahrenheit and %.2f in Kelvin\n",f,k);
             break;
    case 2:  printf("Enter Fahrenheit Temperature: ");
             scanf("%f",&f);
             c=((5*(f-32))/9);
             k=((5*(f-32))/9)+273;
             printf("\nThe Temperature is %.2f in Celsius and %.2f in Kelvin\n",c,k);
             break;
    case 3:  printf("Enter Kelvin Temperature: ");
             scanf("%f",&k);
             c=k-273;
             f=((9*(k-273))/5)+32;
             printf("\nThe Temperature is %.2f in Celsius and %.2f in Fahrenheit\n",c,f);
             break;
    default: printf("\nError. Please Restart The Program\n");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the respective changes that what you need to change.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
//Declare Variables
float ce; //Celcius
float fa; //Fahrenheit
char in; //Input form user
float go; //If a loop should keep running

printf("Would you like to convert into Celsius 'C' or Fahrenheit 'F'?\n");

//scanf("%d", &in);
scanf("%c", &in);

go = 1;
while (go == 1) {
    if ((in == 'F') || (in == 'f'))  { //If the user wants to convert from Fahrenheit
        //Stop the loop
        go = 0;

        //Ask the user the temperature they would like to convert
        //printf("What temperature F would you like to convert to C?\n");
        printf("What temperature F would you like to convert to C?\n");

        //Get the input from the user
        scanf("%f", &fa);

        //Crunch the Numbers
        ce = ((fa - 32)/1.8);

        //Print the answer
        printf("The temperature in Celcius is %lf\n", ce);

    } else if ((in == 'C')|| (in == 'c')) { //If the user wants to convert from Celcius
        //Stop the loop
        go = 0;

        //Ask the user the temperature they would like to convert
        printf("What temperature C would you like to convert to F?\n");

        //Get the input from the user
        scanf("%f", &ce);

        //Crunch the Numbers
        fa = (32 + (ce * 1.8));

        //Print the answer
        printf("The temperature in Fahrenheit is %lf\n", fa);

    } else {
        //make sure the loop will continue running
        go = 1;

        //Print an error message
        printf("That is an invalid input, please enter either a 'C' of 'F'\n");

        //Take the input again
        scanf(" %c", &in); // because of \n characters entered at the end of previous scanf() statement
    }
}

//End the program
return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you look at the previous answer you will see why your second use of `scanf("%c", &in);` will fail.

Comment: "why your *second* use of `scanf("%c", &in);` will fail. "

Comment: Oops, i thought that i made a change before.. thanks for reporting   edited just