# How to get a whole sentence as input using scanf()

Tags: c

I want to get a character and a string and a sentence then write each one of them in a new line. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    const int MAX_LEN=100;
    char ch;
    char s[MAX_LEN];
    char sentence[MAX_LEN];
    scanf ("%c",&ch);
    scanf("%s",&s);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &sentence);

    printf("%c\n",ch);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    printf("%s\n",sentence);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jerry no &s is a pointer to the array, not a pointer to a pointer to the array.

Comment: @Fredrik when s is passed to scanf, it is a pointer to the array (`char *`). And &s doesn't work because it is another level of indirection (`char (*)[MAX_LENGTH]`). That's why removing the & works.  Maybe the exact wording I used was wrong - I guess technically what I should have said was "char s[MAX_LEN]; means that when s is passed to a function that a pointer to the first character of the array is passed instead. But then scanf("%s",&s); means that you are passing a pointer to the array which isn't the same thing."  But the advice to use `scanf("%s",s);` was right.

Comment: @Jerry yes I was refering to the wording. People often get confused when talking about pointers to array when in fact they mean a pointer to the first element. So always a good idea to be pedantic in the wording, I think at least.

Comment: @Fredrik Fair enough.

Comment: ObAntiScanf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-to-parse-input-instead-of-scanf/

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - Your comment above contains the mechanics, but what it boils down to is that mis-matching format specifiers in either `scanf()` or `printf()` results in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12830110/645128)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

```
char s[MAX_LEN];
...
scanf("%s",&s);
```

Use of the `&` in this case is wrong.  `s` is created here as an array type, so its symbol by itself already points to the location of the first element, (its address) and has type `char *`, which agrees with the `"%s"` format specifier used in the `scanf` statement.  Prepending `s` with the `&` changes its type to `char(*)[100]`, which is no longer compatible with `"%s"`.  [Using mismatched format specifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864590/645128) with `scanf()` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), *which is far worse than your program simply being mal-formed, it is unpredictable.*

Note that with warnings turned on (eg, in *GCC* by compiling with `-Wall`) it should result in a message describing all of this.  On my system (not GCC) the following message is issued:

[image]

Likewise, when in debug mode with appropriate settings during runtime I see the following assert:

*"Parameter type mismatch, expecting pointer to char but found pointer to aggregate or user defined."*

By the way, when I allowed execution to continue after this warning message the code appeared to work normally, i.e. it output the content entered into `stdin`.  But that is the nature of undefined behavior, [anything can happen.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

The fix here is to simply replace this:

```
scanf("%s",&s);
```

With either this:

```
scanf("%s",s);  //okay
```

or this;

```
fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);//better
s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = 0; // optional, if need to eliminate the newline
```

either approach works as a replacement for those places in your code where you use an `&` on an array.

Aside:  It is also a good practice to use variable names that self describe themselves. Consider using something more descriptive than `s`, eg: `char string[MAX_LEN];`  or `char string_array[MAX_LEN];`.

Comment: And the same with `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &sentence);`