# char array to long results in unexpected value

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, sign-extension

I tried to convert a byte array to a long

```
long readAndSkipLong(char*& b)
{
    unsigned long ret = (b[0] << 56) | (b[1] << 48) | (b[2] << 40) | (b[3]<<32) | (b[4] << 24) | (b[5] << 16) | (b[6] << 8) | (b[7]);
    return ret;
}
```

My shifting  seems to be not right. For the intended value

```
152  --> 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10011000
```

I get:

```
-104  --> 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 10011000
```

Any idea where the bug is?

Comment: What compiler is this?  May be long is 32-bits, no?

Comment: 64 bit windows machine, but I think 32 bit visual studio

Answer (score 3):

It's because of type promotion and sign extension. Every value in your `char` array is signed, and bit-shifting is an integer operation. When you use the shifting operator, it evaluates to an `int`, and because your `char`s are signed, shifting them would produce signed `int`s.

The last (rightmost) byte has `1` as the sign bit. When promoted to an `int`, its value becomes `-104` by sign extension. As you ORed the rest of the numbers, all the `1` bits remained unaffected.

To avoid this problem, you can cast each `char`s to `unsigned long` before shifting and ORing.

Another thing you can do is bitwise ANDing each `char` with `0xff` like `((b[i] & 0xff) << 24)`. ANDing with `0xff` would produce an `int`, keeping the least significant 8 bits intact and zeroes to the left, no sign extension.

Comment: after char being promoted to int, shifting that many bits is basically UB. I'd suggest constructing two int32_t first then connect them together. Or, maybe better, `union` an `uint64_t` with a `uint6_t[8]` then use a loop to fill it in.

Comment: @user3528438 using `long long` will also do that.

Comment: casting each char to long had no effect - could you post code?

Comment: @Anthea sorry I was wrong at that - when you cast `char` to `long`, both types are signed and sign extension happens. You can cast to `unsigned long`, or AND the value with `0xff` first. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I implemented as Sid Heroor intended and casted each char to uint8_t. Afterwards I tried your solution with the ANDing with 0xff and it also works. I am not sure which solution is better...

Comment: casting to `unsigned long` won't work because `long` is a 32-bit type on Windows and can't store 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. [`char` can be signed or unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/995714), hence shouldn't be used storing for data types other than characters.

   In C, C++ and most C-like languages, any types narrower than `int` [must be promoted to `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11985774/995714) in an expression, and your statement will be treated like this

   ```
    unsigned long ret = ((int)b[0] << 56) | ((int)b[1] << 48)
                      | ((int)b[2] << 40) | ((int)b[3] << 32)
                      | ((int)b[4] << 24) | ((int)b[5] << 16)
                      | ((int)b[6] <<  8) | ((int)b[7]);
   ```

   If `char` is signed, it'll be promoted to `int` using **sign extension**. As a result the top bits will be filled with 1s if the byte value is negative.

   In MSVC `char` is signed by default. You can use `/J` to make char unsigned, which will solve part of your problem. But then another problem arises:
2. In Windows [`long` is a **32-bit** type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/384502/995714), consequently **you can't pack 8 bytes into it**. Moreover `int` is also 32-bit on most modern systems, and after promoting `b[i]` to int [shifting more than 31 is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11270492/995714) which is what your program does.

So to fix all the problems portably you need to:

- Cast all `b[i]` to `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`, or masking the high bits by ANDing it with 0xFF like 0605002 suggested. Or simply change the type of `b` to `unsigned char&*` instead of `char&*`
- Change the return type to a type at least 64-bit wide like `(unsigned) long long`, `(u)int64_t` or `(u)int_least64_t`

The result may look like this

```
uint64_t readAndSkipLong(unsigned char*& b)
{
    return ((uint64_t)b[0] << 56) | ((uint64_t)b[1] << 48)
         | ((uint64_t)b[2] << 40) | ((uint64_t)b[3] << 32)
         | ((uint64_t)b[4] << 24) | ((uint64_t)b[5] << 16)
         | ((uint64_t)b[6] <<  8) | ((uint64_t)b[7]);
}
```

or

```
uint64_t readAndSkipLong(char*& b)
{
    return ((uint64_t)(uint8_t)b[0] << 56) | ((uint64_t)(uint8_t)b[1] << 48)
         | ((uint64_t)(uint8_t)b[2] << 40) | ((uint64_t)(uint8_t)b[3] << 32)
         | ((uint64_t)(uint8_t)b[4] << 24) | ((uint64_t)(uint8_t)b[5] << 16)
         | ((uint64_t)(uint8_t)b[6] <<  8) | ((uint64_t)(uint8_t)b[7]);
}
```

However you don't actually need to write a function to reverse endian. There are already `ntohll()` and `htonll()` for that purpose

```
reversedEndian = ntohll(originalValue);
```

If the input must be a `char` array then just copy the value to a `uint64_t`

```
memcpy(&originalValue, &b, sizeof originalValue);
reversedEndian = ntohll(originalValue);
```

You can further reduce the whole thing to `reversedEndian = ntohll(*(int64_t*)&b);` if [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/995714) is allowed because on x86 unaligned access is generally permitted

Answer (score -1):

Couple of things to think about

1. include `cstdint` and use `std::uint64_t` and `std::uint8_t` for you types so that there is no issues with sign.
2. The logic also depends on whether your machine is little endian or big endian. For Little Endian machines, you need to put your least significant byte first and then go higher. Your logic is for Big Endian.
3. It's possible that you are having a count overflow. A better way would be to explicitly declare a `uint64_t` and use that.

Here's a bit of code I wrote for bytes to `uint64_t` on a little endian machine.

```
std::uint64_t bytesToUint64(std::uint8_t* b) {
    std::uint64_t msb = 0x0u;
    for (int i(0); i < 7; i++) {
        msb |= b[i];
        msb <<= 8;
    }
    msb |= b[7];

    return msb;
}
```

**EDIT by OP (implemented Tip 1):**

```
long readAndSkipLong(char*& b)
{
    std::uint64_t ret = 
        ((std::uint8_t)b[0] << 56) | 
        ((std::uint8_t)b[1] << 48) | 
        ((std::uint8_t)b[2] << 40) | 
        ((std::uint8_t)b[3] << 32) | 
        ((std::uint8_t)b[4] << 24) | 
        ((std::uint8_t)b[5] << 16) | 
        ((std::uint8_t)b[6] <<  8) | 
        ((std::uint8_t)b[7]);
    b+=8;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks, actually your code does not work for me but your tipp to use std::uint64_t and std::uint8_t I updated your answer with my working code for future references!

Comment: `(std::uint8_t)b[0] << 56` will **not** work because `(std::uint8_t)b[0]` will be promoted to int which doesn't contain 64 bits. And you're still returning `long` which is not a 64-bit type on Windows