# Why does printing char sometimes print 4 bytes number in C

Tags: c

Why does printing a hex representation of char to the screen using printf sometimes prints a 4 byte number?

This is the code I have written

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char testStream[8] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 0x3f, 0x9d, 0xf3, 0xb6};

   int i;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
      printf("%c = 0x%X, ", testStream[i], testStream[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And following is the output:

```
a = 0x61, b = 0x62, c = 0x63, d = 0x64, ? = 0x3F, � = 0xFFFFFF9D, � = 0xFFFFFFF3, � = 0xFFFFFFB6
```

Comment: Many conversions that each need explanation: 1) `0x9d`  --> `char` 2) `testStream[i]` -- > `(int)` as part of variadic function 3) mis-match print specifier `"%X"` and `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printf adds extra \`FFFFFF\` to hex print from a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090616/printf-adds-extra-ffffff-to-hex-print-from-a-char-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`char` appears to be signed on your system. With the standard "two's complement" representation of integers, having the most significant bit set means it is a negative number.

In order to pass a `char` to a vararg function like `printf` it has to be expanded to an `int`. To preserve its value the sign bit is copied to all the new bits (`0x9D` → `0xFFFFFF9D`). Now the `%X` conversion expects and prints an `unsigned int` and you get to see all the set bits in the negative number rather than a minus sign.

If you don't want this, you have to either use `unsigned char` or cast it to `unsigned char` when passing it to `printf`. An `unsigned char` has no extra bits compared to a `signed char` and therefore the same bit pattern. When the unsigned value gets extended, the new bits will be zeros and you get what you expected in the first place.

Comment: @chqrlie I corrected that and tried a small explanation on why you have to go  unsigned before going wider.

Answer (score 2):

From the C standard (C11 6.3.2.1/8) description of `%X`:

> The **unsigned int** argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned
>   decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X) in the style dddd; the
>   letters abcdef are used for x conversion and the letters ABCDEF for X
>   conversion.

You did not provide an `unsigned int` as argument<sup>1</sup>, therefore your code causes undefined behaviour.

In this case the undefined behaviour manifests itself as the implementation of `printf` writing its code for `%X` to behave as if you only ever pass `unsigned int`.  What you are seeing is the `unsigned int` value which has the same bit-pattern as the negative integer value you gave as argument.

---

There's another issue too, with:

```
char testStream[8] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 0x3f, 0x9d, 0xf3, 0xb6};
```

On your system the range of `char` is `-128` to `+127`. However `0x9d`, which is `157`, is out of range for `char`. This causes implementation-defined behaviour (and may raise a signal); the most common implementation definition here is that the `char` with the same bit-pattern as `(unsigned char)0x9d` will be selected.

---

<sup>1</sup> Although it says `unsigned int`, this section is usually interpreted to mean that a signed `int`, or any argument of lower rank, with a non-negative value is permitted too.

Comment: Just for the record, arguments with lower rank (like short or char) work here because they promote to int or unsigned int according to the "default argument promotions" for variadic or unprototyped functions.  (Same reason that float promotes to double, which means there is no printf conversion that works for a float if you pass one in hand-written asm.) [Is char default-promoted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11985774) / [What default promotions of types are there in the variadic arguments list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22844360)

Comment: I think on an implementation where `char` is unsigned (e.g. the standard C ABI for ARM), `char` would promote to `unsigned` and the behaviour would be well-defined even for a strict reading of the standard.

Comment: @PeterCordes if `sizeof(int)>1` then unsigned char (and unsigned plain char) promote to signed int

Comment: Oh right, otherwise they're distinct types!  (Which in real implementations like that will still have the same object representation, but still UB in theory.)  Good point.  Anyway, I was commenting based on your footnote that signed `int` is allowed too, in practice, and wanted to point out for future readers why that made it ok to pass a `char` without having to manually cast to `int` on normal implementations on machines with int wider than char.

Answer (score 1):

On your machine, `char` is signed by default. Change the type to `unsigned char` and you'll get the results you are expecting.

**A Quick explanation on why this is**

In computer systems, the MSB (Most Significant Bit) is the bit with the highest value (the left most bit). The MSB of a number is used to determine if the number is positive or negative. Even though a `char` type is 8-bits long, a `signed char` only can use 7-bits because the 8th bit determines if its positive or negative. Here is an example:

```
Data Type: signed char
  Decimal: 25
   Binary: 00011001
           ^
           |
           --- Signed flag. 0 indicates positive number. 1 indicates negtive number
```

Because a `signed char` uses the 8th bit as a signed flag, the number of bits it can actually use to store a number is 7-bits. The largest value you can store in 7-bits is 127 (`7F` in hex).

In order to convert a number from positive to negative, computers use something called two's-compliment. How it works is that all the bits are inverted, then `1` is added to the value. Here's an example:

```
Decimal: 25
 Binary: 00011001

Decimal: -25
 Binary: 11100111
```

When you declared `char testStream[8]`, the compiler assumed you wanted `signed char`'s. When you assigned a value of `0x9D` or `0xF3`, those numbers were bigger then `0x7F`, which is the biggest number that can fit into 7-bits of a signed char. Therefore, when you tried to `printf` the value to the screen, it was expanded into an `int` and filled with `FF`'s.

I hope this explanation clears things up!

Answer (score 1):

`char` is signed on your platform: the initializer `0x9d` for the 6th character is larger than `CHAR_MAX` (157 > 127), it is converted to `char` as a negative value `-99` (157 - 256 = -99) stored at offset `5` in `textStream`.

When you pass `textStream[5]` as an argument to `printf`, it is first promoted to `int`, with a value of `-99`.  `printf` actually expects an `unsigned int` for the `"%X"` format specifier.

On your architecture, `int` is 32 bits with 2's complement representation of negative values, hence the value `-99` passed as `int` is interpreted as `4294967197` (2^32-99), whose hexadecimal representation is `0xFFFFFF9D`. On a different architecture, it could be something else: on 16-bit DOS, you would get `0xFF9D`, on a 64-bit Cray you might get `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF9D`.

To avoid this confusion, you should cast the operands of `printf` as `(unsigned char)`.  Try replacing your `printf` with this:

```
printf("%c = 0x%2X, ", (unsigned char)testStream[i], (unsigned char)testStream[i]);
```

Comment: Detail: `0x9d` is the value 157. That `int` value is converted to `char` in `char testStream[] = {... , 0x9d, ...}` and (assuming a signed `char) gets the value of `-99`.

Comment: @chux: thank you for pointing this imprecision, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What seem to happen here is implicit char -> int -> uint cast. When the positive char is being converted to int nothing bad happens. But in case of the negative chars such as 0x9d, 0xf3, 0xb6 cast to int will keep them negative and therefore they become 0xffffff9d, 0xfffffff3, 0xffffffb6. Not that actual value is not changed, that is 0xffffff9d == -99 and 0x9d == -99.
To print them properly you can change your code to

```
printf("%c = 0x%X, ", testStream[i] & 0xff, testStream[i] & 0xff);
```