# printf adds extra `FFFFFF` to hex print from a char array

Tags: c, arrays, printf

Consider the following simplified code bellow. I want to extract some binary data/stream from a file and print it to the standard output in Hexadecimal format.

I got extra 3 bytes `0xFFFFFF`. What's wrong? From where did the extra bytes come?

**output**

```
in:
        2000FFFFFFAF00690033005A00
out:
        2000FFFFFFAF00690033005A00
```

**program.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int i;
    char raw[10] = {0x20,0x00,0xAF,0x00,0x69,0x00,0x33,0x00,0x5A,0x00};
    FILE *outfile;
    char *buf;

    printf("in:\n\t");
    for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
        printf("%02X", raw[i]);

    outfile = fopen("raw_data.bin", "w+b");

    fwrite(raw, 1, 10, outfile);

    buf = (char *) malloc (32 * sizeof(char));
    fseek(outfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buf, 1, 10, outfile);

    printf("\nout:\n\t");
    for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
        printf("%02X", buf[i]);

    printf("\n");

    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `unsigned char` because `0xAF > CHAR_MAX`. Plain `char` is for strings.

Comment: @cremno it actually depends on the system, plain `char` can be either signed or unsigned.

Comment: a lot of duplicates here already, although it's hard to find it right now

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` (e.g. given by `malloc()`) to other pointers! Also: `sizeof(char)` will never differ from `1`, as that is what it is defined to yield by the standard!

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, yes i could find them by searching *printf variable promotion*.  But :) I wasn't knowing about this topic. Thanks to everyone for help.

Comment: If changing the type is not an option, just cast it: `printf("%02X", (unsigned char)buf[i]);`

Comment: [Why does printf not print out just one byte when printing hex?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3555791/995714)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sign extension.  Your compiler is implementing `char` as a `signed char`.  When you pass the chars to `printf` they are all being sign extended during their promotion to `int`s.  When the first bit is a 0 this doesn't matter, because it gets extended with `0`s.

`0xAF` in binary is `10101111`  Since the first bit is a `1`, when passing it to `printf` it is extended with all `1`s in the conversion to `int` making it `11111111111111111111111110101111`, which is `0xFFFFFFAF`, the hex value you have.

**Solution:** Use `unsigned char` (instead of `char`) to prevent the sign extension from occurring in the call

```
const unsigned char raw[] = {0x20,0x00,0xAF,0x00,0x69,0x00,0x33,0x00,0x5A,0x00};
```

All of these values in your original example are being sign extended, it's just that `0xAF` is the only one with a `1` in the first bit.

Another simpler example of the same behavior ([live link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DZDSXspZJyWaFeen)):

```
signed char c = 0xAF; // probably gives an overflow warning
int i = c; // extra 24 bits are all 1
assert( i == 0xFFFFFFAF );
```

Answer (score 7):

That's because 0xAF when converted from a signed character to a signed integer is negative (it is sign extended), and the `%02X` format is for  unsigned arguments and prints the converted value as `FFFFFFAF`.

The extra characters appear because printf `%x` will *never* silently truncate digits off of a value. Values which are non-negative get sign extended as well, but that's just adding zero bits and the value fits in 2 hex digits, so printf `%02` can do with a two digit output.

Note that there are 2 C dialects: one where plain `char` is signed, and one where it is unsigned. In yours it is signed. You may change it using an option, e.g. gcc and clang support `-funsigned-char` and `-fsigned-char`.

Comment: Changing the signedness of char is not really a durable solution...

Answer (score 1):

The `printf()` is a *variadic* function and its additional arguments (corresponding with `...` part of its prototype) are subject to *default argument promotions*, thus `char` is promoted to `int`.

As your `char` has signed<sup>1</sup>, [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation the most significant bit is set to one for `0xAF` element. During promotion signed bit is propagated, resulting `0xFFFFFFAF` of `int` type, as presumably `sizeof(int) = 4` in your implementation.

By the way you are invoking [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), since `%X` format specifier should be used for object of type `unsigned int` or at least for `int` with MSB that is unset (this is common, widely accepted practice).

As suggested you may consider use of unambiguous `unsigned char` type.

---

<sup>1) Implementation may choose between signed and unsigned represention of `char`. It's rather common that `char` is signed, but you cannot take it for granted for every other compiler on the planet. Some of them may allow to choose between these two modes, as mentioned in [Jens's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31090693/586873).</sup>