# Writing ttyUSB snooper failing

Tags: serial-port, hardware, reverse-engineering, hardware-interface

**Summary:** I am writing a ttyUSB snooper. The code is supposed to read(2) data from a serial port and write(2) it over to another serial port. Reading from the serial port works great with /bin/cat but fails with my code.

**Hardware Setup is:** I made an FTDI cross-over cable, and put one end in the Windows XP machine as Com2 and the other end in a modern Linux machine as /dev/ttyUSB0. The Linux machine has a USB to Serial cable that shows up as /dev/ttyUSB1. It is connected to the actual hardware unit I am trying to snoop. I verified, the hardware works great.

**This part works:** I will "cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > /tmp/data" and then have the WinXP machine issue the "read from the device over Com2", and the following six (6) bytes data will be sent over.

```
\x02\x01\x40\x00\x0a\x9e
```

This "packet" is sent 4 times or so with a very slight delay, this appears to be the WinXP code just trying a few times. If I replay this just once, it works.

If I simply do "cat /tmp/data > /dev/ttyUSB1", the hardware device will respond properly suggesting that it received the command. Great!

**Problem and My Code:** I am writing some code to be run on the Linux machine that will read(2) from /dev/ttyUSB0 and write it over to /dev/ttyUSB1 and vice versa. However, for some unknown reason it will only receive 4 bytes in the first "packet", then 5 in the subsequent 3 attempts. Sometimes, the 5 bytes appear slightly "damaged", meaning I see \xffffff for the last or second to last byte. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <strings.h>

void hexdump(char *data, int size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%02x ", data[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main() {
    int fdzero;
    int fdone;

    int maxfd;

    fd_set sockrd;
    struct timeval timer;

    char data[10];
    int size;
    char tmp;

    fdzero = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);
    if (fdzero == -1) {
        perror("Failed to open /dev/ttyUSB0");
        return 1;
    }

    fdone =  open("/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR);
    if (fdone == -1) {
        perror("Failed to open /dev/ttyUSB1");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fdzero > fdone)
        maxfd = fdzero;
    else
        maxfd = fdone;

    printf("Enter loop\n");
    for(;;) {
        bzero(data, 10);
//      fflush(NULL);
        FD_ZERO(&sockrd);
        FD_SET(fdzero, &sockrd);
        FD_SET(fdone,  &sockrd);

        timer.tv_sec = 60;
        timer.tv_usec = 0;

        select(maxfd+1, &sockrd, NULL, NULL, &timer);

        if (FD_ISSET(fdzero, &sockrd)) {

            size = read(fdzero, data, 10);
            if (size == -1) {
                perror("Failed to read /dev/ttyUSB0");
                break;
            }

            size = write(fdone, data, size); 
            if (size == -1) {
                perror("Failed to write to /dev/ttyUSB1");
                break;
            }
            printf("ttyUSB0 -> ttyUSB1: %d\n", size);
        }


        // This portion does not trigger yet, but its a mirror
        // Yes, I know...bad code :(
        else {
            size = read(fdone, data, 10);
            if (size == -1) {
                perror("Failed to read /dev/ttyUSB1");
                break;
            }
            size = write(fdzero, data, size);
            if (size == -1) {
                perror("Failed to write to /dev/ttyUSB0");
                break;
            }
            printf("ttyUSB1 -> ttyUSB0: %d\n", size);
        }

        // Used to monitor what is read()/write()
        hexdump(data, size);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I actually run this code, I see this:

```
# cc snoop.c -o snoop
# ./snoop
Enter loop
ttyUSB0 -> ttyUSB1: 4
02 00 40 ffffff9e 
ttyUSB0 -> ttyUSB1: 4
02 00 40 ffffff9e 
ttyUSB0 -> ttyUSB1: 4
02 00 40 ffffff9e 
ttyUSB0 -> ttyUSB1: 5
01 02 00 40 ffffff9e 
ttyUSB0 -> ttyUSB1: 5
01 02 00 40 ffffff9e 
ttyUSB0 -> ttyUSB1: 5
01 02 00 40 ffffff9e
```

*Notice that only 4 or 5 bytes are being received and subsequently sent over at any given time. Not 6. Also, notice that the "packet" is distorted. What in the world would cause that???*

**Rationality if you're interested:** I have old software that ONLY runs on Windows XP and will NOT work in a VM (this is a known issue). I would love to capture the traffic going over the serial port. I purchased a WinXP machine just to do this.

Comment: I suspect this is related to the parity bit?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so your two questions here:

> Sometimes, the 5 bytes appear slightly "damaged", meaning I see \xffffff for the last or second to last byte.

This is because of how printf interprets the data coming in([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090616/printf-adds-extra-ffffff-to-hex-print-from-a-char-array) may be of interest).  It is being passed in as a `char`, which is signed.  The high-order bits are being interpreted in this case.  To fix this part, your `hexdump(char* data, int len)` should be either `hexdump(unsigned char* data, int len)` or use a byte-sized type such as `uint8_t`, so that your signature looks like `hexdump(uint8_t* data, int len)`.

> However, for some unknown reason it will only receive 4 bytes in the first "packet", then 5 in the subsequent 3 attempts.

This is almost certainly due to the fact that you do not set any settings on the serial port.  One of the characters that you have is `0x0A`, which is the linefeed character.  This is either being ignored by the serial port driver, or translated into a different character all together.  To fix this, you must set the serial port settings to be raw and not translate any characters that come in.  I generally do something like the following:

```
struct termios newio;
if( tcgetattr( fd, &newio ) < 0 ){ /* error handling here */ }    

/* Set some default settings */
newio.c_iflag |= IGNBRK;
newio.c_iflag &= ~BRKINT;
newio.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL;
newio.c_oflag = 0;
newio.c_lflag = 0;
newio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
newio.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;

/* Set our baud rate */
cfsetospeed( &newio, B9600 );
cfsetispeed( &newio, B9600 );

/* Character size = 8 */
newio.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
newio.c_cflag |= CS8;

/* One stop bit */
newio.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;

/* Parity = none */
newio.c_iflag &= ~IGNPAR;
newio.c_cflag &= ~( PARODD | PARENB );
newio.c_iflag |= IGNPAR;

/* No flow control */
newio.c_iflag &= ~( IXON | IXOFF | IXANY );

/* Set our serial port settings */
if( tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &newio ) < 0 ) { /* error handling code here */ }
```

If you don't want to set the serial port settings this way, I've written a [small library](https://github.com/rm5248/CSerial) which should abstract the small details out for you.

Comment: That looked like it did the trick!
Oddly enough, it works for a while and then suddenly the connection stream fails. I am not certain why and the software I am snooping in on does not produce an error message. Are there any other connection settings that might result in a better connection?

Comment: There aren't any other settings that I can think of.  The settings that I posted I derived from [GTKTerm](https://fedorahosted.org/gtkterm/), although I may have missed a setting.