# Why does fgetc() return int instead of char?

Tags: c, variables, fgetc

I would like to copy binary file source to file target. Nothing more! The code is inspired from many examples found on the Internet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char ch;

    fp1 = fopen("source.pdf", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("target.pdf", "w");

    while((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
        fputc(ch, fp2);

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;

}
```

The result differs in file size.

```
root@vm:/home/coder/test# ls -l
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 14593 Feb 28 10:24 source.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   159 Mar  1 20:19 target.pdf
```

Ok, so what's the problem?

I know that char is unsigned and get signed when above 80. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31090695/3657691).

This is confirmed when I use `printf("%x\n", ch);` which returns approximately 50% of the time something like sometimes `FFFFFFE1`.

The solution to the my issue would be to use `int` i.s.o. `char`.

Examples found with `char`: [example 1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fgetc-fputc-c/), [example 2](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-copy-file/)
[example 3](https://www.w3schools.in/c-program/copy-file/), [example 4](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/write-a-program-to-copy-the-contents-of-one-file-into-another-using-fputc.html), ...

Examples found with `int`: [example a](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm), ...

I don't use fancy compiler options.

Why are virtually all code examples found returning fgetc() to an `char` i.s.o. an `int`, which would be more correct?

What am I missing?

Comment: `int ch` - change `char ch` to this.

Comment: @coderredoc, yes, I know this works, but how come there is so much code out there using `char`. How come the code using `char` works at all?

Comment: I will write an answer on this if I get time.

Comment: You're missing the point that most code out there on the internet (indeed most *anything* out there on the internet) is crap :-)

Comment: You could just use `fread` and `fwrite`, you know.

Comment: @Daniel Kamil Kozar, I know, but your solution eats more memory. I have to deal with huge files. My solution takes more time, I know. My initial question was completely theoretical. I would like to understand why so much code (even on well reputated sites) use `char` in connection with `fgetc`. There must be a reason ... !

Comment: Lot's of code is broken — every piece of code that saves the result of `getchar()`, `getc()` or `fgetc()` into a variable of type `char` is broken.  People don't care.  The name `getchar()` is misleading because it returns an `int`.  But there's nothing you can do except ignore sites where `char` is used to store the result of the character input functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ISO C mandates that `fgetc()` returns an `int` since it must be able to return every possible character *in addition to* an end-of-file indicator.

So code that places the return value into a `char`, *and* uses it to detect EOF, is generally plain wrong and should not be used.

---

Having said that, *two* of the examples you gave don't actually do that.

One of them uses `fseek` and `ftell` to get the number of bytes in the file and then uses *that* to control the read/write loop. That's could be problematic since the file can actually change in size *after* the size is retrieved but that's a different problem to trying to force an `int` into a `char`.

The other uses `feof` immediately after the character is read to check if the end of file has been reached.

---

But you're correct in that the easiest way to do it is to simply use the return value correctly, something like:

```
int charInt;
while ((charInt = fgetc(inputHandle)) != EOF)
    doSomethingWith(charInt);
```

Comment: Unbelievable that so many sites show wrong code (using `char`)! Many thanks for the explanation! Yes, you are right - 2 of my examples use different ways to control where to stop (EOF), but my initial question was more about the `char`/`int` issue I hit.

Comment: @geohei: Well, I know from my own experience that w3schools is ... err, less than ideal ... when it comes to code quality (and this is *my* opinion of course), the others I've never looked into. But, honestly, if you're getting your code snippets nowadays from anywhere but SO, you're probably doing it wrong :-)

Comment: BTW: C has an automatic promotion to `int` for all calculations (and function arguments), so `char` will not bring the expected optimization.

Answer (score 5):

Well the thing is most of code you saw then is wrong. There are 3 types of `char` - `signed`, `unsigned` and plain char. Now if plain char is by default signed then a character with decimal value `255` will be considered equal to `-1` (EOF). This is not what you want. (Yes decimal value `255` won't be representable in signed char but it's implementation defined behavior and on most ones it will store the bit pattern `0xFF` in the `char`).

Secondly if `char` is `unsigned` then it `EOF` will be considered as `0xFF` that is also wrong now and comparison would fail. (Knowing that `EOF` is `-1` it will be converted to `CHAR_MAX` which is `255` or `0xFF`).

That's why `int` is considered so that it can hold the value of `EOF` correctly and that is how you should use it.

Comment: Good answer, since it covers extra aspects I didn't think of, the signedness issues.

Comment: @paxdiablo.: Oh silly  me, you read that comment? :) Thanks anyway and learning from you guys.

Comment: ... and that covers the EOF issue. Many thanks to all!

Comment: BTW ... K&R is always open on my desk :)