# Unexpected result after printing a string in c

Tags: c, string

The code is -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *filevar;
    filevar = fopen("file", "r");
    char copy [100];
    int i = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        char ch = fgetc(filevar);
        if(ch==EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        copy[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n%s", copy);
    fclose(filevar);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it the out put I get is

> textblabla■a

file content is -

> textblabla

Changing the file content changes the random charecters at end

Comment: `char ch` needs to be `int ch`.

Comment: You have to add a NUL character (`'\0'`) after the last character if you want to use `copy` as a string like in `printf("\n%s", copy);`

Comment: [Why does fgetc() return int instead of char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49063518/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main issues.

1. `ch` has to be `int`
2. You do not null character terminate the string

```
        int ch = fgetc(filevar);
        if(ch==EOF)
        {
            copy[i] = 0;
            break;
        }
        
        copy[i] = ch;
        i++;
```