# Why extra 'ÿ' added when writing into a .txt file in C?

Tags: c, file-handling, clion, writetofile

I searched about this problem everywhere, but none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

```
char currentChar;
FILE *fp_read = fopen("../input.txt", "r");
FILE *fp_write = fopen("../textArranged.txt", "w");
while (!feof(fp_read)){
      currentChar = fgetc(fp_read);
      ...
}
```

I tried to change the while condition (using getc()), but it didn't work.

Comment: see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/995714)

Comment: Just a recommendation: write first to a buffer then write to the file. Currently you are writing every single byte on its own.

Comment: disks are block devices so reading block-by-block is much more efficient

Comment: Do `fopen` with `"rb"` and `"wb"` for binary mode. And `fgetc` returns `int`.

Comment: 'ÿ' is character code 0xff, what remains of EOF when the code truncates it by storing it in a char.  In other words, fgetc() tried to tell you that it encountered the end of the file, but it got copied to the output file instead.

Comment: see [Why does `fgetc()` return int instead of char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49063518/995714)

Answer (score 3):

`feof()` seems to return `0` after reading the last byte of the file. It returns `1` **after** `fgetc()` already made the attempt to read one more byte after the end of the file.

When `fgetc()` makes the attempt to read data after the end of the file, `fgetc()` returns `-1`.

If you perform `fputc(x, ...)` and `x` is not in the range `0...255`, `fputc()` will actually write the byte `(x & 0xFF)`.

On nearly all modern computers, `(-1 & 0xFF)` is `0xFF` which equals the character `'ÿ'`.

So the following happens:

- ...
- Your program reads the last byte of the file using `fgetc()`
- It writes that character using `fputc()`
- Although there are no more bytes left in the file, `feof()` returns `0` because you did not make the attempt to read bytes after the end of the file, yet.
- Your program calls `fgetc()` and because there are no more bytes left, `fgetc()` returns `-1`.
- Your program calls `fputc(-1, ...)` which writes the character `'ÿ'`.
- `feof()` returns `1` because `fgetc()` already tried to read bytes after the end of the file.