# Function of (char)getchar() in C programming

Tags: c

My friend asked me what is `(char)getchar()` which he found in some online code and I googled and found 0 results of it being used, I thought the regular usage is just `ch = getchar()`. This is the code he found, Can anyone explain what is this function?

```
else if (input == 2)
{
    if (notes_counter != LIST_SIZE)
    {
        printf("Enter header: ");
        getchar();
        char c        = (char)getchar();
        int tmp_count = 0;
        while (c != '\n' && tmp_count < HEADER)
        {
            note[notes_counter].header[tmp_count++] = c;
            c = (char)getchar();
        }
        note[notes_counter].header[tmp_count] = '\0';
        
        printf("Enter content: ");
        c         = (char)getchar();
        tmp_count = 0;
        while (c != '\n' && tmp_count < CONTENT)
        {
            note[notes_counter].content[tmp_count++] = c;
            c = (char)getchar();
        }
        note[notes_counter].content[tmp_count] = '\0';
        
        printf("\n");
        notes_counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar)  returns an `int` (since it can also return `EOF` which is outside the range of a `char`) - without the cast you should be getting a compiler warning about an implicit narrowing conversion

Comment: Note that code like `while (c != '\n' && tmp_count < HEADER) { note[notes_counter].header[tmp_count++] = c; c = (char)getchar(); }` does not behave well if it encounters EOF before a newline.  The code should use `int c;` instead of `char c;` and should test the integer against EOF.

Comment: *"...which he found in some online code..."* - there is the first problem. Be very wary of "online code", the person posting it may have much less experience than you do with the language. "Online References", like for example [C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) are good authoritative references to consult. Specifically [7.21.7 Character input/output functions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7) will answer your question.

Comment: [Why does fgetc() return int instead of char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49063518/995714)

Comment: The only purpose of `(char) getchar()` is to indicate to the reader that the code should be discarded and that the author is not to be trusted.  It is a novice mistake.

Answer (score 5):

`(char)getchar()` is a mistake. Never use it.

`getchar` returns an `int` that is either an `unsigned char` value of a character that was read or is the value of `EOF`, which is negative. If you convert it to `char`, you lose the distinction between `EOF` and some character that maps to the same `char` value.

The result of `getchar` should always be assigned to an `int` object, not a `char` object, so that these values are preserved, and the result should be tested to see if it is `EOF` before the program assumes a character has been read. Since the program uses `c` to store the result of `getchar`, `c` should be declared as `int c`, not `char c`.

It is possible a compiler issued a warning for `c = getchar();` because that assignment implicitly converts an `int` to a `char`, which can lose information as mentioned above. (This warning is not always issued by a compiler; it may depend on warning switches used.) The correct solution for that warning is to change `c` to an `int`, not to insert a cast to `char`.

About the conversion: The C standard allows `char` to be either signed or unsigned. If it is unsigned, then `(char) getchar()` will convert an `EOF` returned by `getchar()` to some non-negative value, which will be the same value as one of the character values. If it is signed, then `(char) getchar()` will convert some of the `unsigned char` character values to `char` in an implementation-defined way, and some of those conversions may produce the same value as `EOF`.

Answer (score 3):

The code is a typical example of incorrect usage of the `getchar()` function.

`getchar()`, and more generally `getc(fp)` and `fgetc(fp)` return a byte from the stream as a positive value between `0` and `UCHAR_MAX` or the special negative value `EOF` upon error or end of file.

Storing this value into a variable of type `char` loses information. It makes testing for `EOF`

- unreliable if type `char` is signed: if `EOF` has the value `(-1)` it cannot be distinguished from a valid byte value `255`, which most likely gets converted to `-1` when stored to a `char` variable on CPUs with 8-bit bytes
- impossible on architectures where type `char` is unsigned by default, on which all `char` values are different from `EOF`.

In this program, the variables receiving the `getchar()` return value should have type `int`.

Note also that `EOF` is not tested in the code fragment, causing invalid input strings such as long sequences of `ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ` at end of file.

Here is a modified version:

```
else if (input == 2)
{
    if (notes_counter != LIST_SIZE)
    {
        int c;
        // consume the rest of the input line left pending by `scanf()`
        // this should be performed earlier in the function
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;

        printf("Enter header: ");
        int tmp_count = 0;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
            if (tmp_count + 1 < HEADER)
                note[notes_counter].header[tmp_count++] = c;
        }
        note[notes_counter].header[tmp_count] = '\0';
        
        printf("Enter content: ");
        tmp_count = 0;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            if (tmp_count + 1 < CONTENT)
                note[notes_counter].content[tmp_count++] = c;
        }
        note[notes_counter].content[tmp_count] = '\0';
        
        printf("\n");
        notes_counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Re “`EOF` cannot be distinguished from a valid byte value 255”: You seem to assume `EOF` is −1, and converting 255 to signed `char` will produce −1. `EOF` can be any negative `int` value, and the conversion of an out-of-range value to a signed integer type is implementation-defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `EOF` is defined as `(-1)` on all platforms I have seen so far. Converting a byte value of `255` to a signed `char` is indeed implementation defined, which is unfortunate as characters read from a stream almost always get stored into a `char` array. An implementation that would store a value such that `(unsigned char)(char)255  != 255` would be insane.

Comment: Re “`EOF` is defined as (-1) on all platforms I have seen so far.”: So? “I have only seen X, therefore X” is not a valid engineering principle. The C standard is clear: C 2018 7.21.1 3 says `EOF` has a negative `int` value and nothing further. There is no reason to add any assumption to that; it cannot provide any benefit and can only cause bugs.

Comment: Re “store a value”: Storing bytes in a `char` array is different from converting to `char`. Bytes in an array will be reinterpreted according to the encoding of their type. Conversions are performed in an implementation-defined manner. And, no, other methods of conversion are not insane. Clamping instead of wrapping is sensible. Trapping for out-of-range is sensible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I agree that `EOF` could be any negative value and it would be safer if it were outside the range of type `char`, but I have never seen it implemented this way... `char c = 255;` converts an out of range `int` value to type `char`. There is no *reinterpretation* involved in this case.