# C char data type showing more than 2 bytes

Tags: c, types, char

Here's a simple code

```
unsigned char t = 0xFC; // this is 252 in decimal, and -4 if it is signed char.
printf("t: %d 0x%01X 0x%02X 0x%03X 0x%04X 0x%08X\n", t, t, t, t, t, t);
// expecting result: 
// t: 252 0xFC 0x00FC 0x000FC 0x000000FC 0x00000000000000FC
printf("(signed char)t: %d 0x%01X\n", 
                      (signed char)t,  
                      (signed char)t); // expecting result: -4 0xFC
```

but what it actually print out is:

```
t: 252 0xFC 0xFC 0x0FC 0x00FC 0x000000FC
(signed char)t: -4 0xFFFFFFFC
```

It seems that the compiler is treating 1 byte = 4 bits
And that a singed char t is showing 0xFFFFFFFC when I ask for showing only 1 byte, what is going on?

Comment: Two hex digits correspond to one byte, so you're seeing 4 bytes getting printed, not 8. `signed char` got implicitly converted to `int`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions

Comment: When you pass an integer value of a type smaller than `int` to `printf` it will be implicitly *promoted* to `int`. Which is signed. And the promotion includes *sign extension*.

Comment: Please state the compiler version, settings and flags

Comment: Did you check docummentation (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf ) on for the correct format specifier to print a 8bit value, or signed char, or unsigned char? I think you want those with `"hh"`.

Comment: *`and -4 if it is unsigned char`*?!?! That is, at best, one very confusing comment.  If it's unsigned the value can't be negative.

Comment: You need to recycle your C books. The size of any variant of `char` is 1, not 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing hexadecimal characters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c)

Comment: duplicates: [printf adds extra `FFFFFF` to hex print from a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31090616/995714), [Why does printf not print out just one byte when printing hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3555791/995714)

Comment: You lie to printf and tell it that you are passing an `int` and then an `unsigned int` while you are in fact passing `signed char`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your question.

**1. Possible typo**

> `unsigned char t = 0xFC; // this is 252 in decimal, and -4 if it is unsigned char.`

Most probably "if it is ***unsigned***" is a typo, because unsigned numbers don't have a sign.

**2. Misinterpretation of width field**

> `printf("t: %d 0x%04X\n", t, t); // expecting result: 252 0xFC`

The "0x" is not part of the conversion, and you tell `printf()` to use at least 4 digits, filling up with zeroes. And so the actual output is correct:

> `t: 252 0x00FC`

**3. Additional unawareness of the system's width of `int`**

> `printf("(signed char)t: %d 0x%04X\n",`
>                       `(signed char)t,`
>                       `(signed char)t); // expecting result: -4 0xFC`
> ...
> Why is the (signed char)t has 8 bytes? should it be 2 bytes as mentioned in so many C text books?

Apparently you know about integer promotion, but you don't know the width on an `int` in your system, and it is 4 bytes. Books on standard C telling you that an `int` has just 2 bytes are so old, you should drop them.

Additionally you are mixing "byte" and "hex digit". A single hex digit is 4 bits wide, to cover the range from 0x0=0b0000 to 0xF=0b1111. A byte is commonly 8 bits wide. So, the hex value "FFFFFFFC" has 8 digits, but these give 4 bytes.

You tell `printf()` to use at least 4 digits, filling up with zeroes. Since the number to print has 8 digits, you get the correct output:

> `(signed char)t: -4 0xFFFFFFFC`

Comment: I edited my answer after I did more experiment. It is even more confusing now. Have you tired it on your computer?

Comment: Please reread the documentation of `printf()` and see where your assumptions are wrong. Apparently you still don't understand it. -- BTW, please do **not** change the original code in the question as it renders answers meaningless, disregarding the effort put in it. If you have something new in the same issue, **add** it, please! When you have done this, notify me and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I figured it out. Apparently it was  integer promotion that I forgot about.